# Edit record on new page via Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout-mapping-plugin

I want to load a record on a new page via knockout.js.  Can anybody guide me how i can do this.

I have id in url like **`http://localhost:2313/company/addedit/23`**

now i want to load data against this id.

Comment: I have store the Id in ViewBag.Id

Comment: You want to load some info to your page via request to url http://localhost:2313/company/addedit/23 where 23 is company id and  it stored in ViewBag.Id ?

Comment: no on page load i will have id in viewbag i want to load data on page load for example. $.get(url, ViewBag.Id)... I tried to assign id via knockout but did not succeeded then i did it jquery.  Can u help me how i can do it via knockout

Answer (score 0):

You could assign id to some js variable in View:

View code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">    
       var companyId = @ViewBag.Id;
   <script>
```

And in javascript you just could use that variable, like:

```
$.get(url + "/" + companyId, function(data) {
// process data
});
```

Or you could pass id through data-attribute of html tag, like:

```
<span id="categoryId" data-category="@ViewBag.Id"></span>
```

And in js:

```
$.get(url + "/" + $('#categoryId').data('category'), function(data) {
// process data
});
```